# How to get the sharedPreference value after reboot phone using BroadcastReceiver?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-broadcast

**A.java :**  In this class shared prefreence is stored. I have using below snippet.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(A.this);
Editor edit = prefs.edit();
edit.putString("Key1", key);
edit.putString("Key2", secret);
edit.commit();
```

**BroadCastReceiver.java :** I want to get the value of Key1, Key2 when I reboot my phone. for this I have using below snippet.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    String a = prefs.getString("Key1", null);
    String b = prefs.getString("Key2", null);
}
```

**Query :**

Is this problem by context or not

**Output :**

I am getting null value. I tried this format in other Activity run fine but in broadcastReceiver got `null` value.

If I am chossing the wrong way than correct me ?

Comment: in bot places you sure you are using the same context ?

Comment: I dont think so bcz I tried in two Activity and passing the context of the class In which I am using sharedPreferences and I got the value fro the key @Triode

Comment: final SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences(APP_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); In all the places. Just a suggestion but not really sure what is wrong in your code

Comment: I tried this earlier but .... but getting still the same @Triode

Comment: try to use application context every where

Comment: okay ... lemme ckeck @Triode

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you might using two different Context objects. The [PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#getDefaultSharedPreferences%28android.content.Context%29) call returns the default SharedPreferences for the given Context.

Using the application Context for both should solve your problem. Obtain it in the activity using getApplicationContext() and in the BroadcastReceiver using context.getApplicationContext().

This [article](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/) gives a great overview of Context differences.

---

Update: as [Triode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19541748/how-to-get-the-sharedpreference-value-after-reboot-phone-using-broadcastreceiver/19541954#comment28994190_19541748) comments, it is better to use [Context.getSharedPreferences()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences%28java.lang.String,%20int%29). This always returns a single instance.

Comment: Note though, that the problem (probably) remains if you use different context objects to call getSharedPreferences(). So you still want to use the same context there.

Comment: In case this fixed your problem, please mark this as the solution, so it's easier for others to find.

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences("Name of your preference",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

To get the Object of Shared Preference,

For example,

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(
           "Demo",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        edit.putString("Key1", key);
        edit.putString("Key2", secret);
        edit.commit();


SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(
           "Demo",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String a = prefs.getString("Key1", null);
    String b = prefs.getString("Key2", null);
```